# How to trace the HTTP data received by a Apache Web Server?

Tags: apache, http

How can I trace the HTTP traffic received by an Apache Web Server?

Turning TRACE on does not get me the HTTP data.

Normally to trace this i use a TCP Monitor tool and route the calls to the Web Server via the Monitor tool and see the messages in the tool.

In this scenario, we have a third party solution which i don't have access to or control over sending SOAP/HTTP requests and i want to see the message received as-is by the Apache Web Server.

I can get the data from the back end Java EE server which Apache Web Server forwards the HTTP request to but i was surprised to see that there is no built-in trace mechanism that allows me to capture the HTTP traffic @ the Web Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try mod_dumpio: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Answer (score 1):

Without SSL, you can just use whatever packet capture tool is native to your operating system (tcpdump, wireshark, snoop, iptrace, etc)